# Optional parameters resulting in Undefined Method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model in Rails with an instance method. I want this method to have optional parameters, but trying to use optional parameters is causing an error:

```
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def my_method(param1, param2 = another_defined_variable)
    instance_variable == param2
  end
end
```

Now, in the Rails console, the development environment, or the test environment, if I call this method with different numbers of parameters, I get the following results:

```
my_instace.my_method
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (expected error)

my_instance.my_method(:some_symbol)
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_method' for #<MyModel:0x007fb7a2d9fb50>

my_instance.my_method(:some_symbol, 1)
# Runs as expected.
```

What causes the second one to fail? Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of "example" code.

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't release the real code right now :/

Comment: Nothing in your fake code could cause the fake NameError you mention. Unless you can give us more accurate information, we can't help you. As others have pointed out, however, default values must be literals or constants. You can't use a variable or method name on the right-hand side of `=` in a method signature.

Comment: "I can't release the real code right now". Then release a reasonable facsimile of it that duplicates the problem. When you ask for help debugging something, you HAVE to include working code that demonstrates the problem, otherwise your question is off-topic.

Comment: @theTinMan: Apologies, trying to come up with reasonable code that demonstrates the problem. Unfortunately, this entails isolating the problem, which I am currently attempting to do. I do understand, obviously if you can't see the issue, you can't solve it. I am trying to replicate the issue in a manner that allows for me to either figure out why it isn't working or provide a reasonable demo. Also, why edit the title? Formatting standards I am unaware of?

Comment: Titles don't need the tags artificially added. If the Ruby or Rails can be added as part of the flow of the sentence naturally, then they're ok, but tacking them on doesn't help in any way. The tags we use for the question will suffice. Also titles are a statement or question, so they're normal sentences and follow normal capitalization rules. Those things aren't spelled out directly, but reading a bunch of the meta questions will reveal the overall feel for how Stack Overflow style works.

Comment: One of the interesting things about creating the summarized code to demonstrate the problem is that often we actually solve our problem. Removing the unnecessary stuff lets us narrow it down which can make the issue/bug pop out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can default a param to a variable. Why not do:

```
def my_method(param1, param2=nil)
  instance_variable == (param2 || another_defined_variable)
end
```

Comment: I thought of this when the error showed up. I tried it, but even with ```param2 = nil```, it still generates the same errors as above.

Comment: This *should* work. There must be something else going on in the specifics of your code.

Comment: @evanbikes: I would like to clarify that you are correct about this (and thanks!), however it wasn't the full solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyModel

  def my_instance_method(param1, param2 = 5)
    puts params2 
  end

  def self.my_class_method(param1, param2 = 5)
    puts param2
  end

end


obj = MyModel.new
obj.my_instance_method(4,2) #calls the instance one 
MyModel.my_class_method(4,2) #calls the class method.
```

`my_instance_method:` You can't call this method directly. You have to create an instance of the MyModel class then only you can give a call to it.

`my_class_method:` This is a class level method, you can call it directly with class name i.e. `MyModel.my_class_method`

**Regarding the Default parameter:**

You can set it like params2 = 5. This means if you are not passing any value for this second parameter then 5 will be considered as your second param value. But if you are passing any other value then that will be assigned for param2.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on how this is relevant to the question? I'm using an instance method in this example, as the method checks an instance variable of the object.

Comment: I see the confusion. My bad. I am using it with an instance of a method, not as a class method as shown initially in the OP (bad formatting of the example code on my part). Instance method, being called on an instance when the errors occur.

Comment: Exactly you got my point! Bravo! 
class method: have self keyword & call it by class Name 
Instance method:  call by object 

want to set default parameter mention it in the param, this will be overridden by any new value if you are entering else the default will be captured. Plain and simple :)